# How to remove white spaces in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, removing-whitespace

I am retrieving data from a DB table using `SqlDataReader` in ASP.net. I append the retrieved data in a string builder and after that, dump the contents of the string builder into a text file. My problem is that in that text file white spaces are showing up between one column and another ... How can I remove the excess white spaces from my text file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the code here, what you have written

Answer (score 6):

```
1. Text.Trim();
2. Text.Replace(" ", string.empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private string process(string s)
    {
        int len = s.Length;
        int current=0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);

        while (current < len-1)
        {
            if (!(s[current] == ' ' && s[current + 1] == ' ') &&
                !(s[current] == '\n' && s[current + 1] == '\n') 
                )
            {
                sb.Append(s[current]);
            }
            current++;
        }
        return sb.ToString();

    }
```